# WebDav alternatives? Win server 2003, win 7

Tags: webdav

I have an internal web page that I have an iframe with the source pointing to a webdav folder. This allows the user to drag and drop a number of files on the iframe window which a button on the main page then kicks off a server side task to process the files.

I am looking for an alternative that will allow me to drag a group of files and drop them onto a target area of a web page which will then upload them to the web server.

Ideally this would be in ASP.Net 2,3 or 4.

Any suggestions?

TIA 
J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using multi file upload Silverlight component. It works like a charm and I believe it is available on codeplex.